# What's correct order of resampling, reprojecting and composing ImageCollection in GEE?

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, resampling, google-earth-engine-python-api, composite

I want to resample, reproject and compose an image collection in python using the GEE API.
My script now is this

```
adm0 = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level0");
filter = ee.Filter.inList('ADM0_NAME', ['Philippines'])
phil = adm0.filter(filter)
roi = phil.geometry()

startDate = '2018-01-20'
endDate = '2018-01-28'

sentinel1_vh = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')\
.filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH')).select('VH')\
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))\
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('resolution_meters', 10))\
.filter(ee.Filter.date(ee.Date(startDate), ee.Date(endDate)))\
.filter(ee.Filter.bounds(roi))

def resample_and_reproject(image):
    return image.reduceResolution(reducer = ee.Reducer.mean()).reproject(crs = 'EPSG:32651', scale = 20)

sentinel1_vh_new = sentinel1_vh.map(resample_and_reproject)
medianComposite = sentinel1_vh_new.median()
```

So as you can see, the images in the ImageCollection `sentinel1_vh` have a pixel size of 10m, but I want the images to have a pixel size of 20m (using a .mean() operation). I also want to reproject the images to the crs EPSG:32651. And lastly, I want to compose one image of this ImageCollection using a .median() operation. But if I run this script and ask for `medianComposite.getInfo()`, I get

```
{'bands': [{'crs': 'EPSG:4326',
   'crs_transform': [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
   'data_type': {'precision': 'double', 'type': 'PixelType'},
   'id': 'VH'}],
 'type': 'Image'}
```

it seems that this is not what I want. Who can help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make a composite from a collection, the resulting collection will always *report* a “default default projection” of EPSG:4326, because the collection is made from images which *may* have arbitrarily different projections (so their pixel grids may even be “askew” to each other and not in any way describable as the same coordinate system). This result does not indicate that your reprojection has not taken effect.

You can use the `Image.setDefaultProjection()` algorithm after `median()` to “fix” this, but this doesn't affect the pixel values — it only affects what you see printed, and any future operations that *use* the default projection via `Image.projection()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the scale parameter in many functions, just set it to 20, it will perform a nearest neighbor resampling (default), if you want another algorithm like bilinear or bicubic you need to use .resample() to overwrite the default.
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/resample