# Google Earth Engine reducer changes the scale

Tags: google-earth-engine

When I try to use an reducer on S2 NDVI, it changes the scale:

```
var d1 = '2020-08-01';
var d2 = '2021-08-01';
var addNDVI_S2 = function(image){
  var NDVI = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(NDVI.where(NDVI.gt(-0.05).and(NDVI.lt(0)),-0.05)
    .where(NDVI.lt(0.05).and(NDVI.gte(0)),0.05));
};
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
  .filterDate(d1, d2)
  .filterBounds(g); // some geometry needed, may be drawn by drawing tools
var S2_NDVI = S2.map(addNDVI_S2);
print(S2_NDVI.select('NDVI').first().projection().nominalScale());
var S2_NDVI_STD = S2_NDVI.select('NDVI').reduce(ee.Reducer.stdDev()).rename('STD');
print(S2_NDVI_STD.select('STD').projection().nominalScale());
```

Why and how to avoid that?

Output:

```
10
111319.49079327357
```

Comment: Please make it so your example can be tested, i.e. all variables are defined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's correct order of resampling, reprojecting and composing ImageCollection in GEE?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/428384/whats-correct-order-of-resampling-reprojecting-and-composing-imagecollection-i) (The question is different, but the answer I'd write is exactly the same: `reduce()` here is like the `median()` there.)

Comment: I don't think that answers my question at all

Comment: @M.Nicolas edited

Answer (score 3):

Earth Engine uses a [default projection](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/projections#the-default-projection) for images that have ambiguous spatial information. The default project happens to be WGS-84 at 1 degree resolution (i.e. 111319.49 m, exactly what you have).

What is happening is when you apply a reducer your image can have the multiple projections from images and bands being used so Earth Engine does not know which one to use, hence the default project. You will not need to manually reproject, in fact [it is discouraged to apply a reprojection](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#avoid-reproject). Earth Engine will automatically reproject your result at the final computation projection and scale, either when you display on a map or run an export.

Please check out the [Projection Docs](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/projections) for more information. I hope this helps!

Comment: It looks that somehow `S2` is 10m, but `S2_NDVI` displays as bigger pixels on Map (lower resolution)

Comment: It looks correct to me, see the following script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/fe67e3e1bc66128dbff95be92cd13252. Remember Earth Engine does the reprojection at the scale that is being requested. So if it is zoomed out, the data is being requested at lower resolution (a zoom scale of 10 ≈ 153m resolution) and the resulting pixel size will be that scale