# ee.ImageCollection.sum not preserving dimensions, crs_transform, origin

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to aggregate ERA5-Land data from hourly to daily and having trouble using the sum function on an imagecollection(`datasetreg`) below. `datasetreg` is just the ERA5-Land hourly data filtered to a range of dates and clipped to a small region.

The following function applied on datasetreg:

```
print(ee.Algorithms.Describe(datasetreg.first()).getInfo())
```

returns:
{'bands': [{'crs': 'EPSG:4326', **'crs_transform': [0.1, 0, -180.05, 0, -0.1, 90.05]**, 'data_type': {'precision': 'double', 'type': 'PixelType'}, **'dimensions': [25, 42]**, 'id': 'total_precipitation_hourly', **'origin': [1034, 474]**}], 'id': 'ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY/19500101T01', 'properties': {'hour': 1, 'system:asset_size': 396086600, 'system:footprint': {'coordinates': [[[-76.58504900000003, 38.538395], [-74.16324500000002, 38.538395], [-74.16324500000002, 42.607322], [-76.58504900000003, 42.607322], [-76.58504900000003, 38.538395]]], 'geodesic': False, 'type': 'Polygon'}, 'system:index': '19500101T01', 'system:time_end': -631144800000, 'system:time_start': -631148400000}, 'type': 'Image', 'version': 1679055074199325}

However, when I run the code below to aggregate `datasetreg` from hourly to daily and then print the info on the resulting imagecollection (`daily`):

```
def function (dayOffset): 
    start = i_date.advance(dayOffset, 'days')
    end = start.advance(1, 'days')
    return datasetreg.filterDate(start, end).sum().copyProperties(datasetreg)

daily = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0, numberOfDays.subtract(1))
    .map(lambda dayOffset: function (dayOffset)))

print(ee.Algorithms.Describe(daily.first()).getInfo())
```

I get:
{'bands': [{'crs': 'EPSG:4326', **'crs_transform':** [**1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0**], 'data_type': {'precision': 'double', 'type': 'PixelType'}, 'id': 'total_precipitation_hourly'}], 'properties': {'date_range': [347155200000, 1640649600000], ...

The crs_transform has changed to what looks like some default, and the dimensions and origin are lost.  Is there any way of adding these back to the resulting imagecollection `daily`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's correct order of resampling, reprojecting and composing ImageCollection in GEE?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/428384/whats-correct-order-of-resampling-reprojecting-and-composing-imagecollection-i)